# Can LinqPad be used as a Report Server

Tags: html, linq, reporting-services, report, linqpad

I've heard that charts can be generated in LinqPad and that it produces results in html. Is it possible that it could one day be used as some kind of report server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One day perhaps.

Right now it produces bar charts.

[image]

And, exports to HTML.

And, scripts can be run via a command-line with output to stdout or file.

But, the bar charts aren't in the HTML output. If you want to handle the charting by yourself, you could try the HTML fragment mode to get just the data as XHTML.

Even so, LINQPad gets more awesome with each release!